# Exponential families closed under affine transformations

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, st.statistics, it.information-theory, information-geometry

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a probability space and let $\mathcal{M}$ be an exponential family of probability distributions for $\mu$ of the following form:  There are $\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_n:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and an open convex subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ containing the origin such that: $\nu \in \mathcal{M}$ iff there is some $C>0$ and some $x\in U$
$$
\nu = C \exp\!\bigg(-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\varphi_i(\cdot)\bigg) d\mu.
$$

Are there known conditions on the functions $\phi$ ensuring, or better characterizing when the following "affine closure condition" holds:*for every affine map $T:\mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ and each random-vector $X$ on $\mathbb{R}^k$ with $X$'s law belonging to $\mathcal{M}$ the law of $TX$ also belongs to $\mathcal{M}$?*

Comment: I'm going to make a rash guess that the family of multivariate normal distributions with nonsingular variances is the only family of probability distributions matching this description. But maybe an hour from now it will occur to me that I missed something obvious.